# Why is only one graph showing when using talib SAR?

Tags: python, pandas, stock, ta-lib

I need some help with creating the second graph regarding the SAR analysis. I am able to display one, but it doesn't look right to be honest. The other graph is not even showing for some reason. My dataset is just like any other stock data set; open, close, high, low, etc. My code:

```
# SAR
sar = talib.SAR(data['high'].values, data['low'], acceleration=0, maximum=0)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.title("SAR Model")
plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.plot(sar, label='SAR- HIGH', c='aqua')
plt.plot(sar, label='SAR- LOW', c='lime')
plt.plot(data['close'].values, label='Price', c='darkorange')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[SAR Stock Picture][image: 1]

Comment: don't you overdraw aqua line with lime line as you are passing exactly same data for it?..

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspect is happening right now. Do you know how to fix/avoid it?

Comment: What did you meen by `SAR- HIGH` and `SAR- LOW` labels?

Comment: I figured it out. I thought the high and low data was supposed to give two different graphs. But all the data points from both categories were supposed to be in one graph, not two as I initially thought. I deleted the 'SAR-Low lime' graph and changed the upper one to just SAR. You also have to add acceleration=0.02, maximum=0.2 for it to work